# Get error when I declare progressbar id in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, progress-bar

I want to create a horizontal progress bar in my splash screen activity
but when I write kotlin code to animate it, the id of the progressbar shows in red.

[image]

xml

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"  />
```

kt

```
class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen)
    
    progressBar.max = 1000
    val currentProg = 999
    ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", currentProg)
            .setDuration(4000)
            .start()
}}
```

Comment: Accessing views directly by name has been deprecated. You need to either use `findViewById` or View Binding now. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code like this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen)
    
    findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar).apply {
        max = 1000 
        val currentProg = 999
        ObjectAnimator.ofInt(it, "progress", currentProg)
            .setDuration(4000)
            .start() 
    }
}}
```